# How to get variables from one GUI class passed into another?

Tags: java, swing

I'm building an application which takes in inputs as strings and passes them to another class where my methods are stored to return as int/numbers. In my main GUI window I am able to display this to a textArea. I create another class that opens a new window when a button is clicked. I can get the method to display it, but am unable to have anything the user entered passed unless the new window is open first then I press another button for the result.

Ideally, what I want to happen is that when I press my 'Submit Pop' button, the new window opens and displays the result.

GUI class

```
//The declaration of my textArea results are displayed in the main window
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(22, 354, 354, 230);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        
        JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(psuArea);
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(psuArea));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        System.setErr(printStream);
        
        
        JButton popUp = new JButton("Submit Pop");
        popUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                pw ok = new pw();
                ok.newScreen(in , cpuBrand, cpuLine, gpuBrand, gpuLine, flash, platter, sata, cd, fan);
            }
        });

                //The button that calls my method and passes the variables entered to it.
        JButton btnAdvanced = new JButton("Advanced Results");
        btnAdvanced.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                pcp.displayC(in , cpuBrand, cpuLine, gpuBrand, gpuLine, flash, platter, sata, cd, fan);
            }
        });
```

Result window class

```
package pcbuilder;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class pw {

    private JFrame framePU;
    pccalc pcp = new pccalc("");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void newScreen(String n, String cb, String cl, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pw window = new pw();
                    window.framePU.setVisible(true);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public pw() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        framePU = new JFrame();
        framePU.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 348);
        framePU.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        framePU.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(182, 6, 61, 16);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();
        psuArea.setBounds(6, 26, 438, 246);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(psuArea);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(22, 354, 354, 230);
        
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(psuArea));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        System.setErr(printStream);
    }
}
```

Method class

```
public void displayC(String n, String cb, String cl, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf) {
        
//When called in GUI class total wattage is correct. I may need to modify something in my Results or GUI class to have total wattage display correctly in the popup. 
        curWatt = cpu + cpuO + mobo + gpu + fastStore + slowStore + store + exStore + fan + sound;

        
        System.out.printf("%nBuild Name: %s", buildName);
        System.out.printf("%nCPU - %s %s: %d", cb, cl, cpu);
        System.out.printf("%nCPU OC Needed: %d", cpuO);
        System.out.printf("%nMotherboard: %d", mobo);
        System.out.printf("%nGPU - %s %s: %d", gb, gl, gpu);
        System.out.printf("%nSSD/NVME - %s: %d", fs, fastStore);
        System.out.printf("%nHDD - %s: %d", ss, slowStore);
        System.out.printf("%nUnused Sata/NVME - %s: %d", sa, store);
        System.out.printf("%nCD/DVD/BlueRay - %s: %d", fq, exStore);
        System.out.printf("%nFans - %s: %d", cf, fan);
        System.out.printf("%nOverhead for Sound: %d", sound);
        System.out.printf("%nTotal Estimated Wattage: %d%n", curWatt);
        
    }
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Thanks to the answer, I was able to get the code working. Here is the messy code I used to get it working.

public class pw {

```
test nt = new test();
private JFrame framePU;
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();        
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(psuArea));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
pccalc pcp = new pccalc("");



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */


public void newScreen(String n, String cb, String cl, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            String in = n;
            String cpuBrand = cb;
            String cpuLine = cl;
            String gpuBrand = gb;
            String gpuLine = cl;
            String flash = fs;
            String platter = ss;
            String sata = sa;
            String cd = fq;
            String fan = cf;
            
            
            try {

                lblNewLabel.setText("A different label");

                pcp.buildName(in);
                if (pcp.cpuBrand(cb) == true) {
                    
                    pcp.amdLine(cl);
                    
                } else {
                    
                    pcp.intelLine(cl);
                    
                } 
                
                if (pcp.gpuBrand(gb) == true) {
                    
                    pcp.graphAmd(gl);
                    
                } else {
                    
                    pcp.graphNvidia(gl);
                    
                } 
                
                pcp.driveS(fs);
                pcp.driveH(ss);
                pcp.driveF(fq);
                pcp.driveA(sa);
                
                
                pcp.displayC(in , cpuBrand, cpuLine, gpuBrand, gpuLine, flash, platter, sata, cd, fan);
                framePU.setVisible(true);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Still a bit messy, but it's working the way I want and now I can move onto figuring out how to add a save feature.

Comment: on your `initialize` method in `pw` class, add `framePU.setSize(300, 300);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed all kinds of data into the `newScreen` method of the `pw` class.  But you didn't  **do anything** with any of it.  Worse yet, with your current design, there's really nothing useful you **can** do with it, because the declarations of all your GUI components are hidden inside the `initialize` method, where `newScreen` cannot get at them.

First thing you need to do is pull the declarations of your GUI components out of `initialize` and into member variables at the top level of the `pw` class, where other class members (such as the `newScreen(...)` method) can access them:

```
public class pw {
    private JFrame framePU;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    private JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    pccalc pcp = new pccalc("");
    // ....
    private void initialize() {
        framePU = new JFrame();
        framePU.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 348);
        framePU.setDefaultCloseOperation(
            JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        framePU.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(182, 6, 61, 16);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        psuArea.setBounds(6, 26, 438, 246);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(psuArea);
        
        scrollPane.setBounds(22, 354, 354, 230);
        
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(psuArea));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        System.setErr(printStream);
    }
}
```

Now `newScreen` can actually do something useful with the data that was passed to it---namely, get it displayed by the components of the `pw` window:

```
public class pw {
    private JFrame framePU;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    private JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    //...

    public void newScreen(String n, String cb, String cl, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf) {
        final String txt =
           String.join(" ", "n=",n,"cb=",cb,"cl=",cl/* etc. */);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
//   We're already *in* a pw, so no need for a new one...
//                    pw window = new pw();
//                    window.framePU.setVisible(true);
                    lblNewLabel.setText("A different label");
                    psuArea.setText(txt);
                    framePU.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that helped a lot actually, still new to GUI's and am using a GUI builder within Eclipse so still learning the ins and outs. I wasn't aware you could pass data in like that.